# How to set playback rate from chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

This one if probably for chromecast API devs.

[Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient#setPlaybackRate(double,%20org.json.JSONObject)) and [iOS](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/ios/interface_g_c_k_remote_media_client#a3c2fcacb2ab6dcc3da9ff471501db623) have a `setPlaybackRate` method, but the *Chrome Sender API* doesn't appear to have an equivalent feature.

**Is there a javascript method to do this besides [using sendMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014819/chromecast-browser-how-to-choose-requestid-for-sendmessage-to-urnx-castcom)?**

If not, please consider this a feature request! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you've long since moved on from this problem, but here is what got me rolling on this, and yours was the only question I found about it.

```
playerTarget.setHalfSpeed = function (){
    var media = castSession.getMediaSession();
    castSession.sendMessage("urn:x-cast:com.google.cast.media",{
        type: "SET_PLAYBACK_RATE",
        playbackRate: 0.5,
        mediaSessionId: media.mediaSessionId,
        requestId: 2
    }).then(
        function (a) { console.log('Set playback rate success'); },
        function (errorCode) {
            console.log('Set playback rate error: ' + errorCode);
        });
}.bind(this);
```